# Default query hibernate OneToMany attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

I'm using hibernate 4.0 with jpa and I've a one to many relationship that can load lots of data from database and I set it to lazy load (as the code bellow)

To keep the historic, i never remove the B from database when i want to delete it I simple set the "closed" attribute to true...

The problem is if i try to load all the A instances using:

session.createCriteria(A.class).list();

for each instance hibernate will lazy load the B what are markeds as closed. I would like to know if there are any annotation where i can define to only loads those with "closed" as false. 
Avoiding to specify it at every code I use to load A

```
 public class A {

        @Id
        private Integer id;

        private String fullName;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = B.class)
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
        private List<B> series = new Vector<B>();
}

public class B  {

    @Id
    private Integer id;


    private Boolean closed;
    private Date createdDate;
/**lots of other things**/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/

by default jpa doenst allow it, but hibernate provide an annotation for this case, the solution was:

```
public class A {

        @Id
        private Integer id;

        private String fullName;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = B.class)
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
@Filter(name="bNotClosed")
        private List<B> series = new Vector<B>();
}




  @FilterDef(name="bNotClosed", defaultCondition="closed= :value", parameters=
@ParamDef(name="value",type="boolean"))
    public class B  {

            @Id
            private Integer id;


            private Boolean closed;
            private Date createdDate;
        /**lots of other things**/

        }


        session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                    session.enableFilter("bNotClosed").setParameter("value", false);
```

if my parameters was an integer i could put it literally in defaultCondition="unliked = 123", therefore hibernate was interpreting false as a class attribute and going to error so i must define the value at session creation.